# STM32H743VIH6 after an indefinite time, the PDR_ON ball (TFBGA100), pin F7, burns out

Tags: stm32

I have a custom board for STM32H743VIH6 (BGA 100), used for charging and balancing 3S2P batteries.

The board goes into STOP mode (SVOS5) and wakes up every 3 seconds to measure the current. After a while the microcontroller begins to behave strangely, wakes up on its own and reboots, and warms up.

When the microcontroller was removed from two boards, the same PDR_ON (F7) pin balls (and the boards) were burned out.

The microcontroller is supplied with a 12V/5V MAX17632BATE+ and with a 5V/3.3V NCV8186AMN330TAG; all necessary capacitors and bindings are available.

Please tell me if this could be due to STOP mode, reduced power consumption of the microcontroller, or something else.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's F7? Datasheet for the MCU shows top view, your picture looks at the bottom of the package. Not sure about the orientation, but if ball A1 is top right then the missing ball is actually G5 which is PB2, a GPIO pin.

Comment: Yes, the orientation is not visible in the photo, but it is definitely F7 pin.

Comment: In the photo, A1 is a ball, top left.